# Apache camel: connecting to a ZeroMQ server

Tags: apache-camel, zeromq, jeromq, akka-camel

I’m trying to connect to a **`ZeroMQ`** server using apache `camel`. I’m using the `camel-zeromq` component provided by the `camel-extra` project, but seems that this requires the previous installation of the native `ZeroMQ` library on the system.

Does someone know a way of using the `camel-zeromq` component, i.e. without a need to install these native libraries?

I suppose that this is hardly possible.

If that’s the case:

Is it possible to add somehow these libraries to the project in order to avoid installing them directly on the system?

Another drawback that I see to the `camel` component is that it doesn’t seem to have been updated too often. I already have connected a client to the server using the **`jeromq`** libraries. Does somebody know a way of creating a camel route that uses these libraries?

I would appreciate if someone can enlighten me with some advice. I’m kind of stuck, trying to figure out the best approach to solve this problem I face.

Comment: You can always build your own component around jeromq in you want, it's not that hard !

Comment: That's true, it's not that hard! I already have built my own component. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

I had success by excluding the ZeroMQ Scala binding library from camel-zeromq and including jeromq in my pom.xml.

Like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-zeromq</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeromq-scala-binding_2.10</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jeromq</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```